# Key: 'User.Status' Error:Field validation for 'Status' failed on the 'required' tag

Tags: go, validation

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type User struct {
    Status int16 `validate:"required,oneof=0 1 2"`
}

func main() {
    validate := validator.New()
    user := User{Status: 0}

    if err := validate.Struct(&user); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Success")
    }
}
```

I think the program will output "Success", but it output`Key: 'User.Status' Error:Field validation for 'Status' failed on the 'required' tag`.

When I input `user := User{Status: 1}`, it can out `Success` correctly. Why? Is it because `0` is the default, the validator mistakenly thinks that I didn't pass in `Status`?

Answer (score 0):

Your observation about why the validation fails when `Status` is set to `0` is correct. In Go, if a struct field is of a numeric type and not explicitly initialized, it will have the zero value for its type. For an `int16`, the zero value is `0`. The `validator` package works correctly in enforcing that the field must be present and not have its zero value when the `required` tag is used. However, the interpretation of "required" in the context of numeric fields (especially integers) can be a bit nuanced.

When you set `Status` to `0`, the validator sees that the field is indeed present but it considers `0` as the uninitialized or zero value for an integer. This is a common source of confusion because logically, you have provided a value for `Status`, but from the perspective of the validator, a numeric field with a value of `0` could still be considered "unset" or equivalent to not providing a value, hence failing the `required` validation rule.

However, when you use `1` or any non-zero value for `Status`, it passes the validation because now the field is clearly not in its zero state, indicating that it has been explicitly set.

If you want to allow `0` as a valid value for `Status` and still use the `required` validation rule, you can use a pointer for `Status` or consider custom validation logic. Using a pointer allows `nil` to represent the absence of a value, thus differentiating between "not set" and "set to zero". Here's how you could modify your `User` struct to use a pointer for `Status`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type User struct {
    Status *int16 `validate:"required,oneof=0 1 2"`
}

func main() {
    validate := validator.New()
    status := int16(0)
    user := User{Status: &status} // Now explicitly setting Status to 0

    if err := validate.Struct(&user); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Success")
    }
}
```

This change makes it explicit when `Status` is provided, even if it's `0`, because you're now setting a pointer to `0` rather than relying on the default integer value. This way, the `required` tag will pass if `Status` is explicitly set to any value, including `0`, because the field is clearly not `nil`.